# how to create a table with all the columns having the same property?

Tags: html, css, matrix, layout

such as this:

```
item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, item 5
item 6, item 7, item 8, item 9, item 10
item 11, item 12, item 13, item 14, item 15
```

.....

its like a matrix but all the items are from the same group, not like the normal table where columns means different properties of data on each row.
and I need to realize previous page, next page

Comment: Can you explain it more precisely?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for CSS grid maybe:

```css
.matrix {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.matrix>span {
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="matrix">
  <span>item 1</span>
  <span>item 2</span>
  <span>item 3</span>
  <span>item 4</span>
  <span>item 5</span>
  <span>item 6</span>
  <span>item 7</span>
  <span>item 8</span>
  <span>item 9</span>
  <span>item 10</span>
  <span>item 11</span>
</div>
```

Comment: AHH, thats exactly what I want .. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -2):

To make sure that every column has the same properties, just give them all the same class and change the class.

That way each element will share the same properties of that class.

For example, here, you can edit the .column attribute any way you want and it will affect all columns

```css
.column {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="column">Product</th>
    <th class="column">Description</th>
    <th class="column">Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table</td>
    <td>Something to put things on</td>
    <td>$400</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Chair</td>
    <td>A thing that  you sit on</td>
    <td>$30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Monitor</td>
    <td>Budget computer monitor</td>
    <td>$140</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```